# knitr install from github

Tags: r, github, knitr

I'm looking forward to getting my hands on an update of Yihui Xie's knitr package that includes a new chunk option (collapse). I'm trying to install the development version from github but am getting an error. I'm using:

`install_github("knitr", 'yihui')`

And get the error:

```
Error: processing vignette 'datatables.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
unused argument (encoding = encoding)
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I see a discussion of this issue at: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/398 where the suggestion is to update the evaluate package. I've updated the evaluate package successfully and I also updated the devtools package successfully. Below is my sessionInfo().

Anyone have a suggestion?

ZR

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.5    evaluate_0.5.2  RPostgreSQL_0.4 DBI_0.2-7      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1 digest_0.6.4   dplyr_0.1.2    formatR_0.10   httr_0.2      
 [6] knitr_1.5      memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.2 Rcpp_0.11.0    RCurl_1.95-4.1
[11] stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2    whisker_0.3-2
```

Comment: I can confirm the problem with a similar system. Note that the quoted issue is a year old, so it certainly is no longer valid

Comment: Thanks for checking, I appreciate it. I'm guessing 1.6 will be on CRAN relatively soon, but it would be great to use it now :)

Comment: Installation works now.

Comment: Awesome. Also worked for me. Seems that the github version is not 1.6 but 1.5.25 BUT this version has the collapse argument that I wanted. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the development version of **knitr**, just follow the [instructions for installation](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation) in the README file on Github.

For this particular problem, it was caused by an insufficient version of the **markdown** package at that time, but now the new version of **markdown** is on CRAN, so just run `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` and you should be able to install **knitr** from Github. You do not really need to know these details if you install from RForge as mentioned in the instructions.

Comment: Hi Yihui, great. I didn't see that page and got it running as you see above, but will follow those directions in the future. Thanks for the update!